# Send a string from a express post route back to the client

Tags: javascript, express, nodes

I am trying to send back a string, once computed, as it happens back to the client from a post route on express

On the back end I have a post route:

```js
router.post('/', async (req, res) => { 
 try {
  // Here I do some computation on a succesion that generates a new string everytime
  const foo = 'string that changes and I want to send to client' 
  
 } catch (error) {
   res.status(500).send(error)
 }
})
```

Then on the client I am using axios to send data to post

```js
(async () => {
  try {
    await axios.post('/api/send/', { data })
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
})()
```

Is there a way I could, after sending a post request, get data back from that route once it happens?

I tried to use `res.send()` from the post route but it just makes the functions on the back end fail.

Many thanks.

Comment: what error you get with `res.send()` ?

Comment: Basically it sends an empty string and the functions that the post makes just do not work

Comment: @RapSherlock How would you request the string from the client on this scenario?

Comment: just like Gabriel answer just `res.send("your string here")`

Comment: Sorry it goes to the catch with `Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`

Comment: @RapSherlock I meant from the client to pick it up

Comment: that mean you already send response with that route, check if you use `res.render` / `res.json` within your post route.

Comment: Yeah you were right, I was using res. for something else in another function inside the post route, however I the message shows up again because now I am doing the res.send on a loop

Answer (score 1):

```
router.post('/', (req, res) => { 
try {
    // Here I do some computation on a succesion that generates a new string everytime
    const foo = 'string that changes and I want to send to client' 
    res.send(foo);
} catch (error) {
      res.status(500).send(error)
  }
})
```

This should suffice. If not, you need to detail what your error message is.

Comment: The error reads: `Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`

Comment: Double check your usage of 'router'. I suspect it is causing your issue. This is a really trivial post request and it shouldn't be causing any issues.

Comment: The actual post route is a lot bigger that is just a simple example

Comment: Are you having issues with your other POST routes? Is the actual route that you're having issues with at the path of '/'?

Comment: Actually it turns out I was using res for another request inside, and that was conflicting, fixed that now, but because it goes on a loop after the first res.send which now works the second time it throws the message again

Comment: I'd recommend you post actual code, the example you have is extremely rudimentary , and from what it sounds like, matching nothing what you posted. You cannot respond multiple times in a single request. (Saying this in a kind voice)

Comment: Thank you, I am going to make a variable and then another get router to pick it up better then

Comment: I think you have to check the expected header in your backend and how you send the header from the client